# Sorting file numerically and incrementally

Tags: linux, sorting, ls

So, I have 1000 files in a folderA.

Let's say:

> File_0001, File_0002, File_0003, File_0004, File_0005, . . . , File_1000

Question, how to sort these files every two incremental number and copy these files into another folder (folderB). So that the files in folderB will be like this:

> File_0002, File_0004, File_0006,File_0008, File_0010, . . . , File_1000

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: you want odds and evens or you want two sets of the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use simple cp command:

```
cp File_*[02468] folderB
```

Comment: Silly, it's very simple, why I didn't think about it. Lol. Thanks demostene

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | sort | xargs -n2 echo | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I '{}' echo mv '{}' /folderB
```

the trick is to use `| xargs -n2 echo | awk '{print $2}'` to get the even line.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what's actually wanted, I'd say @demostene's answer is probably right. If OP actually wants alternate files from the list, regardless of possibly skipped numbers, then

```
cp $(ls | awk 'NR%2 == 0 {print $0}') folderB
```

would seem to do the trick. Note the obvious extensions for every third, fourth, or Nth file.